# Questions rolling out two new servers

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

After getting a virus and turning my backserver into our primary I figured it's time time to do the right thing and use both servers in case this happens again.

We're using 1 server for dns, dc, termserver (users log in to the server from their desktops). The server also holds all the applications and documents the company uses. They did this because when the system was first designed there were only 10-15 users. Now we have 40 users and the server is slow and we got wacked with a virus from hell. I was able to remove the virus but we keep getting screwed up.

The only applications we use on the server are vistrax which uses microsoft access, microsoft office, 3 users use sql, and they all use the internet.

So far I reinstalled server 2003 on our backup and moved over AD and the backup server is now the DC. I backed up all the documents my user use and also the databases for the programs we used.

My next step is to format the infected server and reinstall server 2003 and join it to the domain. Since I will be using this server as a file\app server do I install term server and the lic server to the (once infected computer or Do i put it on the new DC)? Once I figure that out I will scan all files and slowly pick and choose what files the users get back. Will I load office and adobe on this new server or again install to dc?

Answer (score 3):

You should have two domain controllers per domain, minimum. You shouldn't have anything else other than AD/DNS installed on your domain controllers. No offense, but that's how you got in to this mess in the first place. You **really** shouldn't install Adobe and Office on a DC.

If you're that tight on money, go and buy yourself a couple of Supermicro 1U miniservers for $300 each and use them as domain controllers *and nothing else.*

Then install your file server, your terminal server, your Quake server, etc., on something else.  *Not on your DCs.*

Comment: ahh so your saying i shouldnt even install anythin on the second dc...  I will look into mini (i`ll tell my owner about it) For now is it ok to put the file server with the backup dc? and then move it once we get the (3rd) server?

Comment: Look, I know that sometimes we have to be realistic and make do with what we have. In the meantime, there is nothing technically stopping you from installing other stuff on your domain controllers. All I'm saying is that in terms of best practice, you should have as little as possible besides AD/DNS installed on your domain controllers, and you should have two DCs or more for redundancy, in case something happens to one of them (such as a virus) you don't have to worry about losing your entire domain.

Comment: agree we are working on that =).. where would i put the lic server and term server on the app server then? thanks soooo much